# Cross domain image file upload issue using CORS - ASP.NET Web API and jQuery

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery-file-upload, cross-domain-policy

I am in a need of uploading cross-domain images using ASP.NET web API and AJAX. I am new to this approach.

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload CORS image" id="btnUpload" />
    </form>
    <div id="response"><!-- AJAX Response --></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //55622
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        function uploadFile() {
            var fa = new FormData();
            fa.append("upload_pass", document.getElementById("fileUpload").files[0]);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:5000/api/upload/imagefile",
                data: fa,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                //dataType: "jsonp",
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    // do something here.
                }
            });
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnUpload").bind("click", function () {
                uploadFile();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**API Controller Method**

```html
using Microsoft.AspNet.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;

namespace WebApiz.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class UploadController : Controller
    {
        [EnableCors("AllowAll")]
        [Route("imagefile")]
        [HttpPost("imagefile")]
        public string ImageFile(object data)
        {
            return data.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I have other Controller methods which are perfectly working with `[EnableCors("AllowAll")]` but this one is giving me the following error:

> HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
>   The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.

I have absolutely no idea how to solve this! I referred to [this](http://blog.kotowicz.net/2011/04/how-to-upload-arbitrary-file-contents.html) and [this](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Cross-domain-uploads). But honestly I did not understand clearly. If somebody please help me with what I am doing wrong and what I need to do to accomplish this that would a life saver for me!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a few things and finally this works for me.

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" multiple="multiple" />
        <input type="button" value="Upload CORS image" id="btnUpload" />
    </form>
    <div id="response"><!-- AJAX Response --></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.support.cors = true;

        function uploadFiles(url) {
            var data = new FormData();

            var files = $("#fileUpload").get(0).files;

            // Add the uploaded image content to the form data collection
            if (files.length > 0) {
                for (var f = 0; f < files.length; f++) {
                    data.append("UploadedImage", files[f]);
                }
            }

            // Make Ajax request with the contentType = false, and procesDate = false
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: data,
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#response").html(response);
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnUpload").bind("click", function () {
                uploadFiles("http://localhost:5000/api/upload/fileupload");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```html
using Microsoft.AspNet.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProjectApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class UploadController : Controller
    {
        private IHostingEnvironment _environment;
        public UploadController(IHostingEnvironment environment)
        {
            _environment = environment;
        }

        [EnableCors("AllowAll")]
        [Route("fileupload")]
        [HttpPost("fileupload")]
        public async Task<object> FileUpload()
        {
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Request;
            var imageUrls = string.Empty;
            var fileName = string.Empty;

            if (httpRequest.Form.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var uploads = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
                for (var f = 0; f < httpRequest.Form.Files.Count; f++)
                {
                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Form.Files[f];
                    var files = new List<IFormFile>();
                    files.Add(postedFile);

                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(postedFile.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                        var fileExtension = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf("."));
                        var randomFileName = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
                        var finalFileName = randomFileName + fileExtension;

                        await file.SaveAsAsync(Path.Combine(uploads, finalFileName));
                        imageUrls += "<img src='http://localhost:5000/uploads/" + finalFileName + "' alt='' /><br />";
                    }
                }

                return imageUrls;
            }

            return "No image were uploaded";
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you [esiprogrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4507394/esiprogrammer) for showing me the way. However I did not use any custom model.

I also referred to these articles:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/uploading-a-file-in-Asp-Net-web-api/
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/288/asp-net-5-uploading-files-with-asp-net-mvc-6
http://blog.kotowicz.net/2011/05/cross-domain-arbitrary-file-upload.html

Answer (score 1):

you need to set parameters of `EnableCors` attribute

To allow all methods, use the wildcard value “*”. The following example allows only GET and POST requests.

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:5000", headers: "*", methods: "get,post")]
```

enable CORS using web.config:

following example Allow CORS for all origins

```
<system.webserver>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webserver>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I used `[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:5000", headers: "*", methods: "get,post")]` but it says `the best overload for EnableCorsAttribute does not have a parameter named origins`. Also, in my other controller methods enabling CORS by '[EnableCors("AllowAll")]' works just fine. I didn't have to parameterize it anywhere. In `Startup.cs` I have Cors configured already in this way: `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory){ app.UseCors("AllowAll"); }` Do I still have to add entries in web.config?

Comment: `services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                p => p.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()));` This is how I set up Cors inside 1Startup.cs > ConfigureServices` method, which tells the system to allow All Origins, All Methods and AllHeaders. So why I have to paramterize `[EnableCors]` at method level inside controller or at `web.config` level/s? In fact other methods with just `[EnableCors("AllowAll")]` works perfectly fine. However, none of them is uploading anything to server.

Comment: it depends, you might want to enable CORS for all methods so you can use web.config or enable it at startup, but if you want to only enable it for some specific method you need to enable it per controller/per action with attributes.

Comment: but i guess your problem is due to another issue not CORS.have u tried to call this method in localhost? why are you using `object` as parameter have you tried to use custom Model instead?

Comment: Yes, I am calling the method in localhost only. My WebAPI and the site consuming the methods are in different ports. And I didn't use a custom model yet.